# Is $(1-\cos z)/z^2$ bounded on $\mathbb C$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a function $f(z) = \frac{1 - \cos(z)}{z^2}$ for $z \neq 0$, $f(0) = \frac{1}{2}$.

I know that this function is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$. So, by using a taylor expansion, I got the series representation for $f(z)$. But, I don't know how to prove that this function is bounded on $\mathbb{C}$.

Is it related to the Liouville's Theorem?

Comment: An analytic function is either constant or unbounded.  It's clearly not one, so....

Answer (score 2):

That function has a removable singularity at zero and is therefore really entire.  By Liouville, no non-constant entire function is bounded.  That function is unbounded.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe, it is a stupid question, so, how could you know that f(z) is non-constant function? is this because of f(z) is not like f(z) = c, where c is constant?

Comment: Compute $f(\pi)$ and $f(2\pi)$.

Comment: Why did you compute those things? I can calculate those things, but, I don't know why I should do that in order for showing f(z) is non-constant.

Comment: @Justin All you need is to find two different points $z_1$ and $z_2$ for which $f(z_1) \neq f(z_2)$.

Comment: I see. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(z)$ were bounded, then Liouville's theorem would imply it is constant.  Is it constant?